# How to serialise the Model with the list containing querysets of that model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class DummyModel(models.Model):
      dummyId             =        models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      assetId              =        models.CharField(max_length=250)
      bounds               =        models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Now i have dummylist containing queryset of DummyModel

```
dummylist=[<QuerySet [<DummyModel>]>, <QuerySet [<DummyModel>]>]
```

Now i have serialiser like this

```
class DummySerialiser(serialiser.ModelSerialiser):

     class Meta:
         model=DummyModel
```

Now i need to generate a json in with list of dummymodel

```
{ 
  {"dummyId":1,
    ....
  },
  {"dummyId":2,
   ....
  }
}
```

Any pointers on this would be a great help. Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**create your serializer like this**

```
class DummySerialiser(serialiser.ModelSerialiser):

     class Meta:
         model = DummyModel
         fields = ('dummyId', 'assetId', 'bounds',)
```

**In your view use `many=True` to serialize list of objects**

```
queryset = DummyModel.objects.all() # assume this is your queryset
serializer = DummySerialiser(queryset, many=True)
dummylist = serializer.data # you will get your required json data
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **`many=True`** in serializer, while serializing the data to serialize a list of objects

```
my_serializer = DummySerialiser(dummylist,many=True)
```

You'll get the required data from  **`my_serializer.data`**